# Windows 10 MediaClip rotation

Tags: windows-10-universal

How can I get video file rotation information using Windows 10 universal platform API?

For instance I have a video of size 1920 x 1080, rotated 90, so effectively it is 1080 x 1920.

The MediaElement control renders fine the video but during processing pipeline one of the steps is affected by this rotation and I need to detect this situation.

Sample MediaInfo from the source file is here: [image: video file properties]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to discover it.
But I have found a workaround, by using this piece of code:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckVideoFileRotated(StorageFile file)
{
    var profile = await MediaEncodingProfile.CreateFromFileAsync(file);
    var mediaClip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(file);
    var videoProp = mediaClip.GetVideoEncodingProperties();

    return profile.Video.Width == videoProp.Height &&
           profile.Video.Height == videoProp.Width;
}
```

I was able to detect if the rotation is in place. Luckily I don't need more specific information if it is 90 or 270 degrees.